# How to return JSON of an Ecto result in Phoenix

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am new to Phoenix, and using it for a backend, and currently am trying to return the result of `Repo.all` as JSON to the user.

I have this working in the following way (in `user_controller.ex`)

```
def index(conn, _params) do
    result = Repo.all(User)
    users = Enum.map(result
        fn user ->
            Map.take(user, [:id, :firstname, :lastname, :username])
        end)
    conn |> json(users)
end
```

but this feels like I'm taking unnecessary steps when there may just be a simple function.

Is this the most idiomatic way to send an Ecto result as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do it, depending on what you exactly want, for example :

- If you want every fields you can use :

```
User
|> Repo.all()
|> Enum.map(fn user -> 
  user |> Map.from_struct
end)
```

This will return all `User` and apply [Map.from_struct](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#from_struct/1) to every user found.

- If you want only specific fields, you can use :

```
from(
    u in User,
    select: map(u, [:id, :email])
) |> Repo.all()
```

This will return an array of map containing only select fields. ([Ecto.Query.API.map](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2))